# git status showing code in untracked files

Tags: git

When I run `git status` the output is:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        $i++
        $value
        create()
        database/seeds/UsersSeeder.php
        each(function
        make())
        make([
        resources/views/layouts/user_demo.blade.php
        resources/views/layouts/user_display.blade.php
        resources/views/layouts/user_display2.blade.php
        toArray()

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What should I do ? should I execute `git add .` because I do not want to mess up with the project.

Comment: Consider not using `git add .` as your default add command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful here. It looks like you accidentally created some files. So this entire list are files you created:

```
    $i++
    $value
    create()
    database/seeds/UsersSeeder.php
    each(function
    make())
    make([
    resources/views/layouts/user_demo.blade.php
    resources/views/layouts/user_display.blade.php
    resources/views/layouts/user_display2.blade.php
    toArray()
```

You will find files in the root path of your project with name `$i++` and `$value` and `create()` and so on. So probably you do not want them added to git, so remove those files if you don't need them.

If you now type `git add .` you will add ALL those files to git. If that happens you could still [reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) before comitting (which your command line prompt will tell you if you did `git add .` and then do `git status`. Or if you also committed but want to change it back you could use [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to remove them again. But rebase only if you are the only one working on that branch, else remove the files and commit again.

Comment: Any comment from downvoter so I can improve myself and the answer?

Comment: This answer doesn't provide much value to the OP. It doesn't suggest how to solve the problem, it doesn't even confirm the OP's hunch that they should not use `git add .` in this situation.

Comment: Ohh I think I accidently created these files in the root while using my editor...I thought it was some problem of git. Thanks I just deleted all those empty files and now its not showing in the git status

Comment: @axiac thanks for your feedback! I partially agree with you and updated the answer accordingly trying to explain why not to use `git add .` and if how to solve it. "It doesn't suggest how to solve the problem" is not true, the answer said "remove those files if you don't need them" which will solve the problem.

Comment: @Raj glad it helped, happy coding!